# Create an R dataframe containing the counts of unique values in another dataframe column

Tags: r, dataframe, key

I have an R dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID number   Code
D001        F11
D001        F12
F002        D13
F002        F11
E003        C12
```

And I want to convert into a dataframe like this with counts for each code per ID (key):

```
ID number   F11  F12  D13  C12
D001         1    1    0    0
F002         1    0    1    0
E003         0    0    0    1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest approach is `table` and coerce it to `data.frame`

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(df1))
      C12 D13 F11 F12
D001   0   0   1   1
E003   1   0   0   0
F002   0   1   1   0
```

---

Or use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = Code, values_from = Code,
       values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)
```

-ouptut

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  IDnumber   F11   F12   D13   C12
  <chr>    <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 D001         1     1     0     0
2 F002         1     0     1     0
3 E003         0     0     0     1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(IDnumber = c("D001", "D001", "F002", "F002", "E003"
), Code = c("F11", "F12", "D13", "F11", "C12")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```